# Vertices of a regular dodecahedron

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, geometry

A [regular dodecahedron](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RegularDodecahedron.html) is one of the five [Platonic solids](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PlatonicSolid.html). It has 12 pentagonal faces, 20 vertices, and 30 edges.

[image: dodecahedron]

Your task is to output the vertex coordinates of a regular dodecahedron. The size, orientation, and position of the dodecahedron are up to you, as long as it is regular.

You may output the coordinates in any order, and in any reasonable format.

If the edge length of your dodecahedron is \$a\$, then the coordinates should be accurate to at least \$a/1000\$.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins.

### Example output

This is one possible output. Your output does not have to match this.

```
{-1.37638,0.,0.262866}
{1.37638,0.,-0.262866}
{-0.425325,-1.30902,0.262866}
{-0.425325,1.30902,0.262866}
{1.11352,-0.809017,0.262866}
{1.11352,0.809017,0.262866}
{-0.262866,-0.809017,1.11352}
{-0.262866,0.809017,1.11352}
{-0.688191,-0.5,-1.11352}
{-0.688191,0.5,-1.11352}
{0.688191,-0.5,1.11352}
{0.688191,0.5,1.11352}
{0.850651,0.,-1.11352}
{-1.11352,-0.809017,-0.262866}
{-1.11352,0.809017,-0.262866}
{-0.850651,0.,1.11352}
{0.262866,-0.809017,-1.11352}
{0.262866,0.809017,-1.11352}
{0.425325,-1.30902,-0.262866}
{0.425325,1.30902,-0.262866}
```

Comment: [Relative Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_dodecahedron#Cartesian_coordinates)

Comment: I believe you mean _relevant_. :)

Comment: @JakeRobb Yes, that was a typo on my part, but it's way too late to fix it now :)

Comment: Could you add to the challenge description that the coordinates have to be 3D, to rule out the silly Haskell answer?

Answer (score 23):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 15 bytes

```
SpherePoints@20
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7P7ggI7UoNSA/M6@k2MHI4H9AEZDlEFwCpNKDUgtyEpNTo0PyIXwH96LMFIc0HSUuLiVdOyUupdj/AA)

20 evenly spaced points on the surface of a unit sphere.

[image: ConvexHullMesh[SpherePoints@20, MeshCellStyle -> Opacity@0.75, ViewPoint -> {2, 2, 2}]]

The more obvious `PolyhedronCoordinates@Dodecahedron[]` is a little bit longer.

Answer (score 12):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>31</s> 25 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
®X‚D3ãsãvy5t<;D>‚*¾š2Ý._«
```

Uses \$\sqrt{3}\$ as the distance of each vector from the origin \$\{0,0\}\$. Will output the following 20 vertex-coordinates:

$$[\{-1,-1,-1\},\{-1,-1,1\},\{-1,1,-1\},\{-1,1,1\},\{1,-1,-1\},\{1,-1,1\},\{1,1,-1\},\{1,1,1\},\{0,-\phi,-\phi-1\},\{-\phi,-\phi-1,0\},\{-\phi-1,0,-\phi\},\{0,-\phi,\phi+1\},\{-\phi,\phi+1,0\},\{\phi+1,0,-\phi\},\{0,\phi,-\phi-1\},\{\phi,-\phi-1,0\},\{-\phi-1,0,\phi\},\{0,\phi,\phi+1\},\{\phi,\phi+1,0\},\{\phi+1,0,\phi\}]$$

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0LqIRw2zXIwPLy4@vLis0rTExtrFDiiidWjf0YVGh@fqxR9a/f8/AA)

**Explanation:**

```python
®X‚             # Push pair [-1,1]
   D            # Duplicate it
    3ã          # Get all possible triplets using the cartesian power of 3
   s            # Swap so the [-1,1] pair is at the top again
    ã           # Also get all possible pairs using the cartesian power of 2
     vy         # Loop over each pair of [±1,±1]:
       5t<;     #  Push the golden ratio: (sqrt(5)-1)/2
           D    #  Duplicate it
            >   #  Increase the copy by 1
             ‚  #  Pair it together with the (sqrt(5)-1)/2
      y       * #  Multiply the values in the pair to pair [±1,±1] at the same positions
        ¾š      #  Prepend a 0 to this pair
          2Ý    #  Push list [0,1,2]
            ._  #  Rotate the triplet that many times to the left
              « #  Merge it to the original list of [-1,1]-triplets
                # (after which the list of 20 triplets is output implicitly as result)
```

---

I started with a port of [this SO C# answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10462220/1682559), but noticed (for \$r=\sqrt{3}\$ at least):

- \$±\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\times\phi\times\sqrt{3}\$ is simply \$±\phi\$
- \$±\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}{\phi}\times\sqrt{3}\$ is simply \$±(\phi+1)\$

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W9aYmMd@t@4pCpCy7hES4crQoeLC8TTh/DsdP7/BwA)

Comment: I'm not sure why the guy uses `ϕ=0.618...`, most people use `ϕ=1.618...` (the two are reciprocals of each other).

Comment: Joined to upvote!

Answer (score 11):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 73 bytes

```python
x={3*(55,),(89,34,0)}
for s in(-1,1)*3:x|={(s*y,*z)for*z,y in x}
print(x)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3PStsq421NExNdTR1NCwsdYxNdAw0a7nS8osUihUy8zR0DXUMNbWMrSpqbKs1irUqdbSqNIGSWlU6lUBphYparoKizLwSjQpNiIFQc2HmAwA)

Same approach as @xnor (I think), i.e. flip signs and rotate coordinates random-ish-ly. Only, I'm being more simple-minded about it ;-)

##### Retired [Python](https://www.python.org), 103 bytes

```python
*x,x[7],x[2]=6*[-55,55]
*y,y[11],_,_,y[2]=3*[-34,0,-89,34,0,89]
for a in x,y:*map(print,a,a[1:],a[2:]),
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY307UqdCqizWOBhFGsrZlWtK6pqY6paSyXVqVOZbShYaxOPBBWgiSNgZLGJjoGOroWljpghoVlLFdafpFCokJmnkKFTqWVVm5igUZBUWZeiU6iTmK0oVUskDSyitXUgVgHtRVmOwA)

Integer coordinates from @alephalpha / @xnor via @Arnauld.

Comment: That's some nifty list assignment you have there

Comment: @xnor still not good enough for beating you I notice

Comment: Ball is in your court, @xnor

Comment: @xnor Any chance this might qualify for that outgolfing bounty of yours? (Would look good in my CV ;-D )

Comment: Oh nice idea doing *all* the sign flips. You definitely qualify for an outgoing bounty! I have to wait for the bounty on this question to expire before I can place it.

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6), 88 bytes

Returns a set of strings, where each string is a triplet `x,y,z`.

This version takes inspiration from [xnor's approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/262078/58563).

```javascript
_=>(g=(s,x,y=x,z=x,k=y)=>k--?g(s.add(x+[,y,z]),k%4?z:-z,x,y,k):s)(g(new Set,55),0,34,89)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcpBCsIwEADAr3gRdnFTBFvQwraP8CgioUmDpiTiFk3y@aiHuc1Dv7VMr/tzVSEaW2euNx7AMQglypyo/HjOyINXanQgjTYG0u5CmcoVyW/bsfSq/Dt57AXBQbCfzdmu1HVIezq0dDxhnWKQuNhmiQ5mQKxf)

#### Commented

```javascript
_ => (               // main function ignoring its argument
  g = (              // g is a helper function taking:
    s,               //   s = output set
    x,               //   x = 1st coordinate
    y = x,           //   y = 2nd coordinate, or x by default
    z = x,           //   z = 3rd coordinate, or x by default
    k = y            //   k = counter, initialized to y
  ) =>               //
  k-- ?              // if k is not 0 (decrement afterwards):
    g(               //   do a recursive call:
      s.add(         //     add to the set:
        x + [, y, z] //       a stringified version of the triplet
      ),             //
      k % 4 ? z      //     rotate by putting z at the beginning
            : - z,   //     or -z if k is a multiple of 4
      x, y,          //     followed by x and y
      k              //     pass the updated counter
    )                //   end of recursive call
  :                  // else:
    s                //   stop and return the set
)(                   //
  g(new Set, 55),    // first call with x = y = z = 55
  0, 34, 89          // second call with (x, y, z) = (0, 34, 89)
)                    //
```

---

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 108 bytes

*-5 bytes by using \$\phi\approx 89/55\$, as suggested by [alephalpha](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9288/alephalpha)*
*-3 bytes by scaling everything up (x55), as suggested by [xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor)*

A full program printing 20 triplets `x,y,z`.

```javascript
[344,900,564,228].map(g=n=>n--&15&&g(n,j=0,print([4,6,8].map(i=>[0,55,89,34][v=n>>i&3]*(v&&n>>j++&1||-1)))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYtBCsMgEAB/s9hmDRo1mMP6EfEgPQSFLpIGT/m7TaFzmsNMzT1/Xkdpp@x@jGisxU0pdKvFZfFpfucmdmIKLCVoB7ALxkoK21H4FNHiiv@sUIj36dBvaGyKnTiEAiY9RQe4vU4T6OuS@vFjjC8)

### Encoding

We use the Cartesian coordinates based on the golden ration [as described on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_dodecahedron#Cartesian_coordinates), but with a different scale.

Each triplet pattern is encoded with the following bit mask:

```
ZZ YY XX NNNN
 |  |  | \__/
 |  |  |   |
 |  |  |   +--> number of triplets
 |  |  +------> x
 |  +---------> y
 +------------> z
```

where \$x\$, \$y\$ and \$z\$ are indices in the lookup array \$[0,1,\phi,\frac{1}{\phi}]\$.

This gives:

| Triplet pattern | x | y | z | N | Bit mask | As decimal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| \$(\pm 1,\pm 1,\pm 1)\$ | 1 | 1 | 1 | 8 | 01 01 01 1000 | 344 |
| \$(0,\pm\phi,\pm\frac{1}{\phi})\$ | 0 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 11 10 00 0100 | 900 |
| \$(\pm\frac{1}{\phi},0,\pm\phi)\$ | 3 | 0 | 2 | 4 | 10 00 11 0100 | 564 |
| \$(\pm\phi,\pm\frac{1}{\phi},0)\$ | 2 | 3 | 0 | 4 | 00 11 10 0100 | 228 |

Comment: You can use `89/55` as an approximation of the golden ratio.

Comment: I think you don't need to divide by 55 because the challenge allows the dodecahedron to be scaled.

Answer (score 7):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 33 bytes

```haskell
k=[0..19]
```

```
[[0^(x-y)^2|x<-k]|y<-k]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P9s22kBPz9AylivNNjraIE6jQrdSM86opsJGNzu2phJE/s9NzMxTsFXITSzwjVcoKMrMK1FI@w8A)

### Explanation

So this answer uses a trick, which some may consider a loophole. Actually uses *two tricks*. So I'm going to explain how it works.

If the OP wants to patch this approach out of the challenge, I will delete my answer.

#### Skew polyhedra

The exact definition of a polyhedron varies from person to person. Some circumstances require that a polyhedron be finite and not self intersect, this gives 5 regular polyhedra, some allow self intersection but still require finiteness, this gives 9 regular polyhedra, some times Euclidean tilings are considered as well giving 12.

However in the beginning of the 20th century Petrie and Coxeter discovered 3 regular polyhedra that hadn't been considered before. These were infinite polyhedra with flat non-intersecting faces, however they didn't have insides, so they hadn't been considered before. Pictured below is a section of the mucube, one of the three:

[image: Mucube]

This discovery lead to a new definition of polytope (and by extension a new definition of polyhedron). This definition was first given by Branko Grünbaum in the paper *Regular polyhedra - old and new*, but has been used pretty extensively. Under this definition vertices (and edges) have exact locations, but the higher dimensional elements no longer needed to have exact interiors. A polygon is just a sequence of vertices pairwise connected by edges, such that you can reach any vertex from any other by following edges. A polyhedron is shape made out of polygons with exactly two meeting at every edge.

For example, classically a polygon needs to be "flat" meaning all of its vertices lie in a plane. However skew polygons can have vertices which lie in higher dimensional space. For example here's a 4-dimensional regular polygon:

[image: Pentagonal-pentagrammic coil]

*Image by Plasmath see [this page](https://polytope.miraheze.org/wiki/File:Pentagon-pentagram_coil.gif) for liscensing*

(We will come back to this particular polygon later)

The same can also be done with polyhedra. Instead of requiring that the vertices of a polyhedron lie strictly in 3D space with each face lying on a plane, you can have polyhedra whose vertices span 4 or greater dimensions, and whose faces are non-planar.

Lots of great work would be done with this definition. I'd especially like to point out the work of McMullen and Schulte. The have a paper classifying all the regular polyhedra in 3-space, which has been summarized in this excellent youtube video:

jan Misali, [there are 48 regular polyhedra](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_hjRvZYkAgA)

This definition is the one I am using in this answer.

Now the challenge says:

> Your task is to output the vertex coordinates of a regular dodecahedron. The size, orientation, and position of the dodecahedron are up to you, as long as it is regular.

So I just need to choose *a* regular dodecahedron. It turns out there are 28 distinct ways to realize the regular dodecahedron {5,3} in Euclidean space. The dodecahedron I chose is the its "Simplex realization". In general you can take any regular polyhedron with \$n\$ vertices and create an fully symmetric realization of it on a \$(n-1)\$-simplex. This is because all the symmetries of a polyhedron are permutations of its vertices. The symmetries of a simplex are *all* the permutations of its vertices. So when we place the vertices of a polyhedron on the vertices of a simplex every symmetry is possible. So this realization is always fully regular with maximum symmetry.

The dodecahedron has 20 vertices so that means the vertices of its simplex realization are the vertices of the 19-simplex. At first glance I've just made my problem much harder.  The vertices of the 19-simplex centered at the origin are *nasty*, way worse than the vertices of the convex regular dodecahedron.

So here's where the second trick comes in. The vertices of a regular \$n\$-simplex are actually really simple if you express them in \$n+1\$ dimensions. If you place each vertex on an axis, all at the same distance from the origin, then permuting the axes is exactly the same as permuting the vertices. So this is fully regular, in fact its the same simplex its just lying on a weird hyperplane.

For example you can give the vertices of the triangle as:

$$
(1,0,0) \\
(0,1,0) \\
(0,0,1) \\
$$

This is a regular 2D triangle. This same trick comes up if you want to represent triangular (or hexagonal) coordinates. Instead of using 2D space and complicated square roots, you can represent them in 3D space as triplets of integers.

So returning to the problem at hand, the 19 simplex can be given in 20 dimensions as all permutations of \$(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)\$. Its symmetries being all permutations of of the coordinate axes.

So in summary, I am giving the vertices for a 19-dimensional dodecahedron in 20 dimensional space.

I can't exactly render this in any way that is helpful. But its faces I can say its faces are the regular 4D pentagon shown earlier. If you want to try to imagine 12 of those in 20 dimensional space.

Comment: @LevelRiverSt I do think it is clear what the OP was imagining, since they even include a picture, but the text does say "as long as its regular" so I'll wait to see if the OP wants to rule on this. As for the second point, polychora are *rank 4* polytopes. Convex polychora are 4-dimensional, but they can be other dimensions too (the cubic honeycomb is a 3d polychoron). Skews like this are still called polyhedra, regardless of the spanning dimension, since they only have 3 ranks of proper elements.

Comment: Clever, but the question says "a regular dodecahedron is one of the five platonic solids" so I think it's clear which dodecahedron OP wanted. Also according to wikipedia and wolfram, an n-dimensional shape is called a polytope, and a polyhedron is specifically 3 dimensional. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytope https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polyhedron.html

Comment: @LevelRiverSt If you disallow certain classes of polytopes rank and dimension are the same thing, but if you allow tessellations or skews this isn't true. In some cases dimension is used in place of rank, however the same source wikipedia is very clear that higher dimensional polyhedra are still called polyhedra in the relevant article: [Regular skew polyhedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_skew_polyhedron).

Comment: Looks like you answered my first comment while I was correcting/deleting it. I was aware of the Jan Misali video, and of the representation of for example the 4-simplex (3-dimensional tetrahedron) in 4 dimensions as all permutations of (0,0,0,1) which can be be moved into 3 dimensions by selecting the vertex (0,0,0,1) and changing its coordinates to (a,a,a,0) where a can take two different values (for this 3D example a=1 is one of them, and happens to be an integer.) By analogy the 20-simplex is a 19 dimensional object with a similarly convenient representation in 20 dimensions.

Comment: I must admit I'm struggling to visualize the embedded skew dodecahedron on this 19 dimensional object, and understand why it is rank 3. (I admit I don't have a clear understanding of rank - is this topological?) However, if we're bending the rules, I would note that the stellated dodecahedron and great dodecahedron also have 12 faces and simpler vertex sets (12 vertices in 3 dimensions, and identical to the icosahedron.)

Comment: @LevelRiverSt I can't help much with visualizing, it's too high. But I can explain why it's rank 3. It's a combinatorial property. A polytope has "elements", these are the vertices, edges, faces, cells, etc. Each element is itself a polytope composed of lower rank elements. So polygons form the faces of polyhedra, polyhedra form the cells of polychora etc. If you take a polygon for example and pull some of its vertices out of the plane to make it 3D, what you have is still a polygon, because its elements are still edges and vertices.  The same can be done with a polyhedron.

Comment: Rank is about the structure of the elements, dimension is about the locations of the vertices. A polyhedron is always made of faces edges and vertices no matter the dimension, that's what sets it apart from polygons and polychora. Polygons have no faces (or 1 face if you count the polygon itself), and polychora have cells.  For visualizing the differences there are two examples I recommend: 1. Euclidean tilings, these are polyhedra (rank 3) but 2 dimensional. 3. Skew polygons, these can be 3D (so not hard to visualize) but are rank 2. https://polytope.miraheze.org/wiki/Skew_hexagon

Comment: I've seen the Petrie polygons in the Jan Misali video, including skew hexagons that exist in 3d space. Example: take the vertices of the cube but instead of looking for the shortest possible cycle, pick cycles of length 6, eg. (0,0,1),(0,1,1),(0,1,0,),(1,1,0),(1,0,0),(1,0,1) zigzagging around the equator of the cube. Every vertex equivalent by symmetry (1/6 rotation about the x=y=z axis combined with a flip in a perpendicular plane.) I can't see a way to construct a symmetrical skew polygon with an odd number of faces in 3 dimensions.

Comment: Your skew pentagons appear to be 4 dimensional & symmetrical. Taking one of your pentagons at random (0,0,0,0,1),(0,0,0,1,0),(0,0,1,0,0),(0,1,0,0,0),(1,0,0,0,0) these correspond to the vertices of a 5 simplex which is 4 dimensional (embedded in 5 dimensions but that can be fixed by moving it.) I can accept that if you take the topological graph of the platonic dodecahedron & assign the vertices from your code to it, you get a kind of 19 dimensional dodecahedron. It doesn't matter how you assign the vertices as ordering of dimensions is arbitrary. Can you confirm if that's the correct topology?

Comment: @LevelRiverSt Yes this is correct. It's the exact same topology as the convex dodecahedron. The pentagons are "Pentagonal-pentagrammic coils" ({5}#{5/2}) which are the only possible regular skew pentagon, and yes in general all the regular polygons in 3-space have an even number of edges.

Comment: The comment about Petrie and Coxeter infinite polyhedra "not having insides" perhaps needs clarifying. They're certainly orientable 2D manifolds without any edges (in the manifold sense, not in the polyhedra sense), so they have two sides, but which is "inside" or "outside" is simply a matter of viewpoint or choice.

Comment: @MartinKealey They do have two sides, but you can't just choose one to be the inside or outside, doing so breaks the symmetry.  If one side is the inside you get concave and convex edges, breaking edge transitivity.  For a simpler example you can look at the [zigzag](https://polytope.miraheze.org/wiki/Zigzag) which partitions the plane into two regions, but choosing one as the inside makes it no longer regular.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 86 bytes

```python
r=[]
for l in[[55]*3,[0,89,34]]*99:l+=(len(r)%11%-2|1)*l.pop(0),;r+=(*l,),
print({*r})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYtBCoMwEADvvsKLkN1ui2kqmBZfEnK0VFiSZfEi6tujbW8zDCPL/MnJ9aKl6BBi9c5acz2lELouoqPQUu/JPWJE7598GQyPySg01jbX@2YB@SZZTAv00rMiE1AlOqXZrKg7lD9/r59DOQA)

Outputs the golden-ratio vertices everyone is using, scaled up by 55, from the approximation of \$ \phi \approx 89/55\$ suggested by alephalpha.

The idea is to take the two vertices \$(1,1,1)\$ and \$(0,\phi,1/\phi)\$ and "randomly" negate entries and take cyclic permutations to reach all 20 vertices, then de-duplicate using sets. Each loop alternates between the two vertices, mutating it by moving the first entry to the back, and possibly negating that entry. Whether to negate is given by `i%11%2` on the `i`'th loop, which happens to hit all 20 vertices in not too many loops. The index `i` is actually tracked by the length of the list `l` of vertices we've generated so far.

---

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 82 bytes

```python
*l,k=0,34,89,718230
while k:k-175or(l:=[55]*3);l+=l.pop(0)*(-1)**k,;k>>=1;print(l)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoUgEADQfadoqdMUmkmW2EWi5YdihhwkiH96e0/@z5lvF6TUCoyUDLoJw4KzDaMzzXte/Gtppd7OPhfFa9q9P8DpyF3iQbIoo0H1VgMQRtq2ZKOU634U61o/)

To be golfed...

Answer (score 4):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 130 bytes

```
A+B:-A=B;A is-B.
A*B*C*G*I*P:-A+P,B+P,C+P;A=0,B+G,C+I;B=0,A+I,C+G;C=0,A+G,B+I.
:-bagof([A,B,C],A*B*C*89*34*55,R),maplist(write,R).
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcwxC8IwEAXgvb/CsV4uQdCCNnS4yxCyBVdxqKAl0JLSFvrz46HDg4/34M1LHvOg1z2VQopbTR1bOqRVs6kIGBx4CBBlUBFZ4lS01J3EXhwsi0kFsbfuZy9bMFWrX/2QP/WDkNE98f92vcH5Ak2D9yNO/Tymdav3JW1vKUwpXw)

Uses the approximation \$\phi \approx 89/55\$ then scaling the vertices by 55.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Answer (score 4):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 16 bytes

```
7Ƃ89\55:ŗÐçxŘ~?ŋ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHHBgqWlJWm6FtvMjzVZWMaYmlodnX54wuHlFUdn1Nkf7V5SnJRcDFUCUwoA)

```
7Ƃ89\55:ŗÐçxŘ~?ŋ
7Ƃ                  Push the list [1,1,1]
  89\55             Push the number 89/55
       :ŗÐ          Pair with its reciprocal ([89/55,55/89])
          ç         Prepend zero ([0,89/55,55/89])
           xŘ~      Non-deterministic rotation ([0,89/55,55/89],[89/55,55/89,0],[55/89,0,89/55])
              ?     Non-deterministic choice ([1,1,1],[0,89/55,55/89],[89/55,55/89,0],[55/89,0,89/55])
               ŋ    Optionally negate each element
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>53</s> 44 bytes

```
≔Ｅ²Ｅ³∨ι∧⊖λ⊘⁺⊖λ₂⁵υＦυＦＥ²⊞ＯΦιν×⊖⊗κ§ι⁰Ｆ¬№υκ⊞υκＩυ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY09DsIwDIV3TpHRkYKEQEydqiIEA7QCLhBaQ6OmSclPxe1D0rIgvDzbz35f3XJTay5DyK0VTwUnPsCakSQbRkoDgpFcNbDD2mCPymEDkjJy4HKMbSW9/fOuL88NXrR2sKVzMeJptnhoQ8BTMumXVHnblgMa7rSBvZAOJ6aKLzfR42/6Tvu7jNqlxNwdVYPvdL2aIHPuOWIL7ZUDz0iX1gkxD9miMiI6BbfRpjQLISxH@QE) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Uses the formula from [this Math.SE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/141653/30622).

```
≔Ｅ²Ｅ³∨ι∧⊖λ⊘⁺⊖λ₂⁵υ
```

Get the points `[1/ϕ, 0, ϕ]` and `[1, 1, 1]`.

```
ＦυＦＥ²⊞ＯΦιν×⊖⊗κ§ι⁰Ｆ¬№υκ⊞υκＩυ
```

For each point, rotate it around the axis `x=y=z`, and also reflect the rotated point in the `xy` plane, and save and process any new points thus found.

```
Ｉυ
```

Output the final dodecahedron.

Answer (score 3):

## Perl, 167 bytes

```perl
sub f{print"@_
"}sub g{$a=shift;map{$_[$_]*(!($a&1<<$_)*2-1)}0..~~@_-1}$p=.5+sqrt 5/4;f g $_,1,1,1 for 0..7;do{@v=((g $_,$p,1/$p,0)x2);f @v[$_..$_+2] for 0..2}for 0..3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NU3dCoIwGL3vKZZ8hPNntpV0ocLeI2QYNRMq1zQJxnz1NaM4cDicH4666Fvu3PA6IWmU7h5jwMUqsIvRGmiq4drJsbg3yoA4gqijcB1Cs6FlCQJHLKXYbgmZZy5SakFVJI@Hpx5Rnu0LiVoEIqELkOw18s1Dce4Nn6ow/GagEpp52uI3w37AJ39CCIiY1f8Jsz@xc@4D)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>18</s>  17 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

<sup>...or 15 with repeats - remove `µQ`.</sup>

```
Ø+ṗ3µØpİƬŻṙJ×€jµQ
```

A niladic Link that yields a list of triples.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASgA1/9qZWxsef//w5gr4bmXM8K1w5hwxLDGrMW74bmZSsOX4oKsasK1Uf//)**

#### How?

Produces the twenty triples as shown on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_dodecahedron#Cartesian_coordinates):

$$(\pm 1, \pm 1, \pm 1)$$
$$(0, \pm \phi, \pm \phi^{-1})$$
$$(\pm \phi^{-1}, 0, \pm \phi)$$
$$(\pm \phi, \pm \phi^{-1}, 0)$$

```
Ø+ṗ3µØpİƬŻṙJ×€jµQ - Link: no arguments
Ø+                - [1, -1]
   3              - three
  ṗ               - Cartesian power -> (+/-1, +/-1, +/-1) "CubePoints"
    µ          µ  - monadic chain - f(CubePoints):
     Øp           -   phi
        Ƭ         -   collect up while distinct under:
       İ          -     inverse
         Ż        -   prefix with zero -> [0, phi, 1/phi]
           J      -   range of length {CubePoints} -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
          ṙ       -   rotate {[0, phi, 1/phi]} left by (vectorises) {that}
                      -> [[phi, 1/phi, 0], [1/phi, 0, phi], [0, phi, 1/phi], ...(8)]
             €    -   for each (rotation):
            ×     -     multiply by {CubePoints} (vectorises)
              j   -   join {that list of lists of triples} with {CubePoints}
                Q - deduplicate
```

Comment: I can't find a way to actually save a byte with it, but `Ær2ị` is a funny alternative to `ØpİƬ`. :)

Comment: I like that that avoids the phi built-in as we have a form of the defining equation right there in our cube points! I was wondering if a set of roots might somehow make for less code in general before I wrote this code too, but I doubted that.

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 55 bytes

```ruby
20.times{|j|p ~0**j*(1.309-k=j/10),1.618**k*1i**j*=0.4}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY/dboMgAIXvfQrSq40AAk5Ks/gkxgu0LtHW6vxZ7Gr36g7dZv1hMSYkH@ecj7IJr33PKamTLK5uXdoV4ItCmMInRhx6wCcvtRl9RowIJiE8QZYM1KPk5d4XTV2BnWVFeVaoMgZVpM7xEXyocxNX4K3MM/CuT3WSXxCo8rLWMLyCTxDleXlMLqqOd1aru7jgUgg4jlDHgdzyfb2/F45ElFCE/64EyPL1NHcd7qLRkPIlxYww5rhc56SmbP8PxmY@lWNjO0X6Gw6blcXIRnGl8HiZOYZNua250YwSISU7ME2H/THz2/5z@@G8pNKlwmWjlTGGTblpDa/mZj6zYryIrn3wcnf2DjPBa2RwnbAVkEwVty7pFApR5CWvBfBxZLdI6T@02@DefwM)

Golfed version using decimal approximations instead of exact formulas (I can't use fractions as Ruby would interpret using integer arithmetic.) Dimensions are now half the ones given in the wolfram page, instead of double, to avoid `j/10*4`. The polar vertices are now listed before the equatorial vertices, to enable the distance from the `z` axis to be calculated as `1.618**k` (1 or 1.618)

I also deleted the `[]` to save 2 bytes, although this impacts readability of the output.

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>85</s> 63 bytes

```ruby
20.times{|j|p [~0**j*z=5**0.5-1+j/10*4,[8/z,4].max*1i**j*=0.4]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZLdboIwFMfveYrGy64t5xRbaxafhHhRkCUYEQa4oLK9uituU8EuTZMmv/P/aHLqQ3K8XCSINi@y5txv@4rEX0Dplp5WilIQiuPLNkSgcxab8MTma1HYjmI@zKxAzNefl@rQNmQWBGlZVLbOSJPaXbYhH3Z3yBryVpcFeXevNi/3jDRl3TqYHMmJpGVZb/K9bbNZ0DkzqaXRmqLQaCCKQhnEMYpooSPDQADjfyNrFsQuW6pIKuYmYAlyTDkKxEhJpzOO4uIfzP38Zs697sDcGR5PKaOQp4qTCvef@WXcp3tu7m0GQhuDS3R0yL9qft1/pu@dx9Qo0Aqvrbwy7tPd0vgk7qHPgzEfSad9@Dj34R9@wqfI0/WGg2GBq3Of95YlLF3lr27leRp2zLqbhJ1b6G8)

The coordinates given in the question are `x,y,z` with the dodecahedron's 5-fold rotational symmetry axis aligned with the `z` axis (It's actually a 10-fold axis for the rotate-and-flip operation.). This program outputs the same coordinates as the ones in the question, but in the format `[z,x+yi]` and scaled. First all the equatorial vertices are output, and then the polar vertices.

`~0**j` alternates the sign of the `z` coordinate as the `x` and `y` coordinates cycle through the 1/10th of a circle rotations.  (`-1**j` would not work because unary minus has lower priority than raising to a power in Ruby.)

Exact coordinates in terms of the golden ratio are given at [the wolfram page](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RegularDodecahedron.html) in formulas 1 and 2. The alternate coordinate system used in other answers is given a little below them on the same page, as well as in wikipedia. This code uses double the scale used in the Wolfram page, to avoid the division by 2 required to calculate the golden ratio. The footer in TIO link scales the coordinates given in the question and moves the `z` coordinate to the beginning for comparison. You still have to squint a bit because I've sorted the coordinates given in the question by `z` value, whereas the above code generates the vertices in an intercalated order with alternating sign of the `z` value.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 24 bytes

```
{+K^_BT3*VM*K.<L+tB.n3Z3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/v1rbOy7eKcRYK8xXy1vPxke7xEkvzzjK@P9/AA)

Uses the same \$\varphi\$ based coordinates that everybody else is using, just multiplied by 10, that is, \$[\pm 10,\pm 10,\pm 10], [\pm 10\varphi, \pm \frac{10}{\varphi}, 0], [0, \pm 10\varphi, \pm \frac{10}{\varphi}], [\pm \frac{10}{\varphi}, 0, \pm 10\varphi]\$.

But there's a really neat simplification here, which is that after I had the integer coordinates, I could use them as the signs for the other coordinates, just adding the need to deduplicate at the end since \$0=-0\$.

#### Explanation

```
    _BT                     # bifurcate 10 on negation (gives us [1,-1])
   ^   3                    # get all possible triplets
  K                         # assign this list to K
                   .n3      # phi
                 tB         # bifurcated on subtracting 1
                +     Z     # append 0 to the pair
             .<L       3    # map [0,1,2] to cyclic rotation on this list
           *K               # get the cartesian product of these rotations with K
        *VM                 # map over vectorized multiplication
 +K                         # add K to this list
{                           # deduplicate to eliminate repeat coordinates
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 226 bytes

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU/BasMwDL3nK3SUmsRLCru0yaAf0FOPYxTFcVN3Sew6ZlBCvj2zyxhsOoj3xNN70iS551UP1jgPUyRiYH8V58Q0NyU9HFmPMCcArbrAEAiy66bdwTl@vJ@802P3QTXM6xf3YOuTumNeZiUlkXc1Tnfn8ZXykl62ECtBvBg3c5XbfRObDG15aNW3ELc5azJJlKZPma3yf/q/UqJwr50lT@p3VL890abLmg12aUm0RBEWokh3Z6K9rvICvIHtj5cVrTMWdQi1wvOnCjAYh1jF8oo2POn7kVaAJVnWbw)

```scala
val p=Seq(-1,1)
val g=(sqrt(5)-1)/2     
((for{a<-p;b<-p;c<-p}yield Seq(a,b,c))++(for{p<-((for{a<-p;b<-p}yield Seq(a,b)).map{case Seq(a,b)=>Seq(a*g,b*(g+1))}.map(0.0+:_));i<-0 to 2}yield p.drop(i)++p.take(i))).foreach(println)
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVJLT8MwDL73V/iYsq1sSFwqhsSdSYjHCaHJa7MukCUhMUgT6m8vblf64HHg@MX@HnYcMtRYVWrvrCcINUr2SLtkHUV28ywzghUqAx8RQC63sGcg0BchhSvv8fB4R16Z4ilO4cEogmXTCfCOGhwqzw/XKpCYLaawiLsSk5yWFLi8tb7lACBczBpaizffcDbCJRyU1PnRAKewmUIWj9z/p/9DrxcrrM6luUVSliVFePUkzmOY8UxwCme/9a3eNPGQSuY3bZImEW/XdXkyDHJgB8vLFsHJUIpr/CCGISbsfIxX9hN76aTJe8O/09QpxDyZQ5rCuh/TW0Lq@cPVNZ9Zb2tk0hZVXZkD2XYVX5usSUnurRMqhsnkiAlfJOPOdKsM6vv@ILrbYMIwUEMYNSccUGK2E45vkLSpNcuojKrqEw)

```scala
import scala.math._

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val pair = List(-1, 1)
    val triplets = for {
      a <- pair
      b <- pair
      c <- pair
    } yield List(a, b, c)
    val pairs = for {
      a <- pair
      b <- pair
    } yield List(a, b)
    val goldenRatio = (sqrt(5) - 1) / 2
    val goldenRatioMultipliedPairs = pairs.map {
      case List(a, b) => List(a * goldenRatio, b * (goldenRatio + 1))
    }
    val prependedPairs = goldenRatioMultipliedPairs.map(0.0 :: _)
    val rotatedPairs = for {
      pair <- prependedPairs
      i <- 0 to 2
    } yield pair.drop(i) ++ pair.take(i)
    val finalTriplets = triplets ++ rotatedPairs
    finalTriplets.foreach(println)
  }
}
```

Comment: 30 byte save: `print("1,1,1;-1,1,1;1,-1,1;-1,-1,1;1,1,-1;-1,1,-1;1,-1,-1;-1,-1,-1;1x,0x,0;0x,0,1x;0,1x,0x;-1x,0x,0;0x,0,-1x;0,-1x,0x;1x,-0x,0;-0x,0,1x;0;1x,-0x;-1x,-0x,0;-0x,0,-1x;0,-1x,-0x".replace("x",".618"))`  :)

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, <s>139</s> <s>137</s> 135 bytes

```perl
sub p{print"@_
"}sub g{($x)=@_;map{$_[$_]*(1-(4*$x>>$_&2))}1..3}p g$_,(55)x3 for 0..7;map{@v=(g$_,89,34,0)x2;p@v[$_..$_+2]for 0..2}0..3
```

[try it online](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@4NEmhoLqgKDOvRMkhnkupFiSQXq2hUqFp6xBvnZtYUK0SH60SH6ulYairYaKlUmFnpxKvZqSpWWuop2dcW6CQrhKvo2FqqllhrJCWX6RgoKdnDtbmUGarAZKzsNQxNtEx0Kwwsi5wKAMapaenEq9tFAtVbFQLJIz//wcA)

Comment: Hi there, welcome to code golf! This is a very good first answer! I hope you enjoy your stay on this site.